# How to evaluate formula with data updated in Apache POI

Tags: excel, apache-poi

All:

I am pretty new to Apache POI. I have a formula in a sheet with reference to some cells from other sheets which will fill that data later, but after I fill all required data in other sheets, and I try to evaluate the formula, it just can not apply the data:

For example,

I have Sheet2 A1 cell with formula "`=SUM(Sheet1!A1, Sheet1!A2)`"

then I set Sheet1 A1 and A2 with 10 and 20, but when I call

```
// cell2A1 is the cell A1 in Sheet2
double v = cell2A1.getNumericCellValue();
```

The v is always 0.00.

**I wonder how to let POI know the data update and apply those value to calculation?**

Comment: Please read [Formula Evaluation](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html) and especially [Recalculation of Formulas](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html#Recalculation+of+Formulas).

Comment: @AxelRichter  Thanks so much, works like charm!